# problem windows seven tor startup

Tags: error

I can not start the browser because it is the first time it happens to me, I have everything working correctly, sorry my English.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkUhm.jpg

Comment: Can you use the button on the bottom left to copy the log and add it to your question, please?

Comment: Tells me that I copied well and 0 log record

Comment: Well, standard set of next steps: check for antivirus or security products and check your windows application logs.

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/7-5-5-could-not-connect-to-tor-port Same as me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on linux, I fixed the problem by quitting all tor.exe processes.
I think what you should do is close all Tor Browser windows, go to Task Manager, look for any *tor.exe* processes and possibly *firefox.exe* processes with "Tor Browser" in the Description column (If you don't see Descriptions then you need to enable it in Task Manager menu > **Select Columns**).

Last, close all those *tor.exe* and *firefox.exe* processes and open Tor Browser again, it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I already did what you said and nothing is more restart so that nothing bothers me and does the same to me. I'm running out of options

Comment: In case my answer didn't work, the last resort would is to reinstall tor browser (from https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) and restart your computer. That should eliminate any corrupt settings and traces you have. (And if it did work, please click "Mark as Answered" for my answer.)

Comment: (For some reason I can't edit my above comment) By the way, to uninstall tor browser completely just delete the folder you installed it in. Nothing is stored in the registry, I think.